# Postgresql : Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to connect postgresql but I am getting this error.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

My pg_hba.conf file is like this.

```
 TYPE  DATABASE        USER            CIDR-ADDRESS            METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I would be much obliged if anyone please be so kind enough to explain whats going on here and how I should correct it.

Comment: Have you checked that the server is started? What os are you using?

Comment: Did you do what the error message says? *"Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections"* . You have not shown what is producing that error message.

Comment: Also, always show your PostgreSQL version, how you installed PostgreSQL, and your OS/distro/version.

Comment: Launch/Inicia con el 

$>docker-compose up

Comment: In my case I had to restart my posgres via:  sudo service postgresql restart

Answer (score 179, accepted):

The error you quote has nothing to do with `pg_hba.conf`; it's failing to connect, not failing to authorize the connection.

Do what the error message says:

> Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections

You haven't shown the command that produces the error. Assuming you're connecting on `localhost` port `5432` (the defaults for a standard PostgreSQL install), then either:

- PostgreSQL isn't running
- PostgreSQL isn't listening for TCP/IP connections (`listen_addresses` in `postgresql.conf`)
- PostgreSQL is only listening on IPv4 (`0.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1`) and you're connecting on IPv6 (`::1`) or vice versa. This seems to be an issue on some older Mac OS X versions that have weird IPv6 socket behaviour, and on some older Windows versions.
- PostgreSQL is listening on a different port to the one you're connecting on
- (unlikely) there's an `iptables` rule blocking loopback connections

(If you are *not* connecting on `localhost`, it may also be a network firewall that's blocking TCP/IP connections, but I'm guessing you're using the defaults since you didn't say).

So ... check those:

- `ps -f -u postgres` should list `postgres` processes
- `sudo lsof -n -u postgres |grep LISTEN` or `sudo netstat -ltnp | grep postgres` should show the TCP/IP addresses and ports PostgreSQL is listening on

BTW, I think you must be on an old version. On my 9.3 install, the error is rather more detailed:

```
$ psql -h localhost -p 12345
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 12345?
```

Comment: I am connecting on localhost port 5432. postgresql.conf ->> listen_addresses = '*', I am connecting on IPv4 and my os is Windows 7.

Comment: I am using Postgrsql 9.0

Comment: I tried these commands but nothing happend

Comment: How is this not marked as the best answer. It's the only answer I've found that helped me fix the problem.

Comment: $ ps -f -u postgres
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
jalal@klein:~/computer_vision/XNAT/xnat/deployments/xnat$ ps auxwww | grep postgres
jalal    17998  0.0  0.0  13692  2240 pts/12   S+   18:16   0:00 grep --color=auto postgres

Comment: I just realized I was connecting to a wrong port *5432* instead of *5433*. Check here  `cat /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf | grep port`. Apartamenty default port changed from version to version.

Comment: @JanuszSkonieczny That's only on Debian/Ubuntu with `pg_wrapper` managed installations. See `pg_lscluster`.

Comment: I think the answer should talk about difference of 127.0.0.1 vs 0.0.0.0 vs localhost and if docker is involved or not between prisma (usually run insider docker container) vs postgres in docker or on native OS.

Comment: @bjm88 Why? Nothing can cover every topic, every virtualisation tool, etc. WTF is "prisma" ? I agree that it's worth addressing container networking to a limited extent, so please add another answer that elaborates accordingly.

Comment: uncommenting and adding `listen_addresses` helped me. Thanks

Comment: Sometimes the user owner of the log folder changes, this command fixes this issue: sudo chown postgres:postgres /var/log/postgresql/ -R

Comment: I did a couple of things  go to postgresql.conf, first one is  check it out for port number , and then after that check pg_hba.conf  file and all of the databases method must be trust instead of md5. When you modify all of things restart your db and try  again . Hope it helps =)

Comment: @ilya_direct Thank you very much for writing that verbosely! I just installed postgres, nuked the server due to the default OS being outdated, and installed postgres on the new OS. Went over everything so quickly I totally forgot to remove the # in the beginning of the line.