# Cannot connect to Postgres from a SpringBoot app running in a docker container

Tags: spring-boot, postgresql-9.1, docker-for-mac

I have a Spring Boot application that is running in a docker container. From this application I am trying to connect to a Postgres DB that is running in localhost. 
I am getting Connection refused error.

I tried solution #1 & #3 mentioned in the below post, but that is also not working.

[Using Docker to launch web app, can't connect to Postgresql DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482716/using-docker-to-launch-web-app-cant-connect-to-postgresql-db?noredirect=1&lq=1)

What I tried so far

1. Spring Boot application.properties has Postgres url as localhost:5432 and
   docker run --add-host [dockerhost ip]  -it and docker run --net=host -it
2. Spring Boot application.properties has Postgres url as [dockerhost ip]:5432
   and docker run --add-host [dockerhost ip]  -it and docker run --net=host -it

Neither of the above is working.

I am using Docker for Mac 1.12.5