# SSH to docker container that refuse to start

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker

My spring boot app is connecting to postgres and I want to set `/etc/hosts` like in [add-postgres-port-hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482716/using-docker-to-launch-web-app-cant-connect-to-postgresql-db) but my container refusing to run when I try to run it using `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 springio/flyaway-postgres` it fails to run in the background because it tries to find localhost inside the container -

```
Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections
```

So how can I run `docker exec [container] nc -v -z localhost 5432` in a container that I cannot run in detach mode?

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the database actually running?  Changing `localhost` to point to somewhere other than 127.0.0.1 doesn't seem like a good idea; there must be a better way to tell the migration tool where your database actually is.

Comment: You can `docker run any-image some-other-command`; for debugging purposes, frequently `docker run --rm -it any-image sh`; but this won't help you reproducibly run migrations.

Comment: The DB runs locally and im able to connect via pg-admin.

Comment: What does "locally" mean?  (On the same LAN?  Inside a multi-process container?  Outside a container, but on the same host?  In a container, but in a different Docker network?)

Comment: Outside of my container on the same host, running he server using postgres pg-admin console and the container is separately running using docker run.

Comment: [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) describes the configuration you need here.  (On non-Linux, configure your application to use the special host name `host.docker.internal`.)  You should not need to adjust `/etc/hosts` anywhere.