# Unable to access greenplum outside the system where it is installed?

Tags: jdbc, greenplum

I have installed greenplum in a AWS linux system and when i am trying to connect to greenplum from java code i am getting an error :

exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Did u add the user which you are trying to connect from java code in pg_hba config file?

Comment: i am unable to find that file, where can i find it in linux and do i need to add ip address of my local system? @AnuraagVeerapaneni

Comment: usually it presents in path "/data/master/gpseg-1/pg_hba.conf". For more info go through this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825734/postgresql-connection-refused-check-that-the-hostname-and-port-are-correct-an

Comment: getting same error , greenplum is on xx.xx.xxx.xxx and i am connecting to greenplum from my java code in local system. I have added listen_addresses ='*' and  host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5 in pg_hba.conf . why am i still facing the issue? @AnuraagVeerapaneni

Comment: First, can you check that the master is listening on 0.0.0.0, port 5432? The "netstat" command will tell you. Second, can you reach the master from your local machine, using "telnet" or "netcat", on the designated port?