# encounter an error while connecting to PostgreSQL in IntelliJ with Spring Boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm experiencing a PostgreSQL connection error when building a new project in IntelliJ with Spring Boot. The error message is as follows, and it appears to be a typical input information error, but I can't seem to find the cause (I've confirmed that the same connection information works when used in a previous project, so it seems to be a configuration issue within the current project).

**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:7773 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.**

However, when I use the same information in IntelliJ's database connection for the project, it connects without any issues.
[database connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XHZl.png)

[application.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNxmz.png)

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRxo9.png)

[application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRhMX.png)

[error_log1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCqfG.jpg)

[error_log2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCbNW.jpg)

"Is there anyone who might know the cause? I've been struggling with this all day. TT"

Comment: just share all information in here not in others.

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and don't post code as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you could solve is:

- Ensure that PostgreSQL is configured to listen on the expected address and port. You can find the PostgreSQL configuration files in the PostgreSQL data directory.
- Try to use your IP address instead of localhost
- Other ways try this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20830893/18567686